# Android Studio - Attr tag error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to build my application I have this error message :

> C:\Users\Kaneda\Documents\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.1.1\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(1) Tag < attr> 'format' attribute value "String" not valid

I don't understand why because I only add few lines since my last build. I've try to Clean my project but nothing change.

Thanks for yout help

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple...

In the xml file it's string and not String

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading you Android SDK - there is a newer version of the support library available.

Comment: The problem is still here :/